# Pass json data for multiple rows in single query for insert

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here i have query for inserting data into table works for single data.But how to insert multiple rows from single query in Postgresql for the given data.

```
 db.query('INSERT INTO position (user_id,company_id,designation,country,city,salary)VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING *', [data.user_id, data.company_id, data.positionDetails.designation,data.positionDetails.country, data.positionDetails.city, data.positionDetails.salary]).then(function(Position) {
        return callback(null, Position.rows[0])
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return callback(null, err);
     })
```

Data (For Multiple insert):

```
{ 
  "user_id":1
  "positionDetails":[
   { 
     "designation": "Developer",         
     "country": "testcountry",
     "city": "testcity",
     "salary": 200
   },{ 
     "designation": "Tester",         
     "country": "testcountry",
     "city": "testcity",
     "salary": 100 
   }
  ],
  "company_id": 1   
}
```

Comment: `insert into position (...) values (... data for row one ...), (... data for row two ...), (... data for row three ...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, but how to pass data for those data for row one, data for two row etc... from data given

Comment: PostgreSQL syntax for inserting multiple rows is just like shown above and how your driver/language constructs such query has nothing to do with Postgres. My advice is to remove postgresql tag and instead put your language+lib tags, since you are having issues with those, not postgres.